# How to read different contents from a text file

Tags: batch-file

I need to read the ID from a file like this:

```
BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 10.0.16299
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Volume C: [OSDisk]
All Key Protectors

    External Key:
      ID: {31116007-D1FB-43CC-A89C-927487BD5F00}
      External Key File Name:
        31116007-D1FB-43CC-A89C-927487BD5F00.BEK

    Numerical Password:
      ID: {C7948F32-F2F0-4E55-AD2E-06E982DFDB4F}
      Password:
        xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxx
    TPM:
      ID: {6497FF93-F678-4317-B5D7-423E9D682BF0}
      PCR Validation Profile:
        0, 2, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11
```

and then run the following command to to export the keys to AD for all IDs

```
manage-bde -protectors -adbackup c: -id {C7948F32-F2F0-4E55-AD2E-06E982DFDB4F}
```

Comment: What have you tried before? What is the goal here? Please review the [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of good question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not willing to utilise another built-in scripting language for this, and your file to read uses Windows standard line endings, I have an alternative idea.

Instead of directly searching for lines with `ID: {…`, you may be able to search for `<Anything><Carriage Return><Line Feed><Space(s)><Password:>`. *You could further refine `<Anything>` should you feel the need, but in this case I do not think it's necessary*:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "Src=input.txt"
Set "Str=Password:"
Set "ID="
(Set LF=^
% 0x0A %
)
For /F %%A In ('Copy /Z "%~f0" Nul')Do Set "CR=%%A"
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FindStr /RC:".*!CR!*!LF! *%Str%" "%Src%">"%TEMP%\_$.tmp"
EndLocal
For /F "UseBackTokens=2Delims={}" %%A In ("%TEMP%\_$.tmp")Do Set "ID={%%A}"
Del "%TEMP%\_$.tmp"
If Not Defined ID GoTo :EOF
manage-bde -protectors -adbackup c: -id %ID%
```

In the example above, I have used `input.txt` as the name of the text file you're reading, please modify that as needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR /f "tokens=2delims={}" %%a IN ('findstr /x /r /c:"  *ID: {.*}" "%filename1%"') DO ECHO manage-bde -protectors -adbackup c: -id {%%a}
```

where `filename1` contains the filename you are examining and the command is being `echo`ed. Remove the `echo` keyword to execute `manage-bde`.

The `findstr` looks for lines that exactly match the pattern `[spaces]ID: {string}` and assigns the string between `{}` to %%a, then displays the required command line, reapplying the `{}`

Answer (score 1):

a pure batch script, which takes advantage of the fact, you look for the key immediately after a "trigger line" (`Numerical Password:`)

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "flag="
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (t.txt) do (
   if defined flag (for %%b in (%%a) do set "key=%%b") & goto :found
   if "%%a" == "Numerical Password:" set "flag=yes"
)
echo not found & goto :eof
:found
echo %key%
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use a [windows script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host) to handle the task? This can be executed directly, using `wscript`, or from a batch file using `cscript`:

```
cscript //nologo myscript.js

var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var file = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\\myfile.txt", 1);
var content = file.readAll();
// Do something with file content
file.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get what want with Regular Expressions and FindStr. Partial solution since I'm lazier than you. ;)

```
c:\projects>findstr {[0-9A-F/-]*}  data.txt
  ID: {31116007-D1FB-43CC-A89C-927487BD5F00}
  ID: {C7948F32-F2F0-4E55-AD2E-06E982DFDB4F}
  ID: {6497FF93-F678-4317-B5D7-423E9D682BF0}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: I overlooked that `all IDs` and created a solution based on the example line**

The following PowerShell one liner will extract the ID from a text file `.\BitLocker.txt`

```
PoSh> Select-String -Path .\BitLocker.txt -Pattern 'Numerical Password' -Context 0,1|ForEach-Object {($_.Context.Postcontext.Trim() -split ' ')[1]}
{C7948F32-F2F0-4E55-AD2E-06E982DFDB4F}
```

To be on topic wrapped in a batch:

```
@Echo off
For /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in (`
    powershell -NoP -C "Select-String -Path .\BitLocker.txt -Pattern 'Numerical Password' -Context 0,1|% {($_.Context.Postcontext.Trim() -split ' ')[1]}"
 `) Do Set "ID=%%A"
 manage-bde -protectors -adbackup c: -id %ID%
```

Comment: We had a correspondent named `Todd` in `alt.msdos.batch` who initially wrote every solution in `qbasic` and then wrapped that `qbasic` program in a few batch lines. He eventually settle down and produced some useful batch, but it was generally agreed that applying a batch wrapper to a solution written in another language was not a batch solution.

Comment: @Magoo, I understand the point you're trying to make, but would suggest in this case that LotPings is simply leveraging a default built in CLI executable in the same way as he would `attrib`, `choice`, `find`, `findstr`, `forfiles`, `ipconfig`, `mode`, `more`, `net`, `ping`, `reg`, `robocopy`, `runas`, `sc`, `setx`, `taskkill`, `tasklist`, `timeout`, `tree`, `where`, `wscript`, `xcopy` etc. The only real difference is that it isn't located in `%__AppDir__%`.

Comment: @Magoo, What a neat story ;-) I was active in amb/ambnt several years ago (with another ID). You do NOT refer to Todd Vargo? I took OPs example line ***too*** literal and as PowerShells `Select-String` has that handy `-Context` parameter, built a solution around that. While my attention is split between batch and PwSh I'm definitly biased towards PwSh when it comes to full fledged RegEx handling.

Comment: @LotPings: I do most certainly make that reference.